# Cmake error:Workspace contains non-catkin packages in it

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm new in ROS. And today when I started to install ROS_adruino_bridge, this error happens. I have searched on the website for this kind of errors, but have no results yet. Did anyone have this kind of problem before? Any suggestions if I cannot use catkin make in my workspace or how can I configure to solve this problem? Thanks.

```
pi@gps_pi:~/ros_catkin_ws $ catkin_make
Base path: /home/pi/ros_catkin_ws
Source space: /home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/src
Build space: /home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/build
Devel space: /home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/devel
Install space: /home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/install
###Running command: "cmake /home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/src -DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/devel -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/install -G Unix Makefiles" in "/home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/build"
-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/devel
-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /opt/ros/indigo
-- This workspace overlays: /opt/ros/indigo
-- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/python
-- Using Debian Python package layout
-- Using empy: /usr/bin/empy
-- Using CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING: ON
-- Call enable_testing()
-- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: /home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/build/test_results
-- Found gtest sources under '/usr/src/gtest': gtests will be built
-- Using Python nosetests: /usr/bin/nosetests-2.7
-- catkin 0.6.18
CMake Warning (dev) at catkin/CMakeLists.txt:5 (project):
  Policy CMP0048 is not set: project() command manages VERSION variables.
  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0048" for policy details.  Use the cmake_policy
  command to set the policy and suppress this warning.
  The following variable(s) would be set to empty:
    catkin_VERSION
  This warning is for project developers.
  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.
-- BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is on
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- ~~  traversing 215 packages in topological order:
-- ~~  - genmsg
-- ~~  - gencpp
-- ~~  - genlisp
-- ~~  - genpy
-- ~~  - angles
-- ~~  - bfl (plain cmake)
-- ~~  - bond_core (metapackage)
-- ~~  - cmake_modules
-- ~~  - class_loader
-- ~~  - common_msgs (metapackage)
-- ~~  - common_tutorials (metapackage)
-- ~~  - convex_decomposition
-- ~~  - cpp_common
-- ~~  - desktop (metapackage)
-- ~~  - diagnostics (metapackage)
-- ~~  - eigen_stl_containers
-- ~~  - executive_smach (metapackage)
-- ~~  - geometry (metapackage)
-- ~~  - geometry_tutorials (metapackage)
-- ~~  - ivcon
-- ~~  - media_export
-- ~~  - message_generation
-- ~~  - message_runtime
-- ~~  - mk
-- ~~  - navigation (metapackage)
-- ~~  - nodelet_core (metapackage)
-- ~~  - octomap (plain cmake)
-- ~~  - openslam_gmapping
-- ~~  - orocos_kdl (plain cmake)
-- ~~  - pr2_description
-- ~~  - python_orocos_kdl (plain cmake)
-- ~~  - qt_dotgraph
-- ~~  - qt_gui
-- ~~  - qt_gui_py_common
-- ~~  - random_numbers
-- ~~  - robot (metapackage)
-- ~~  - robot_model (metapackage)
-- ~~  - ros (metapackage)
-- ~~  - ros_base (metapackage)
-- ~~  - ros_comm (metapackage)
-- ~~  - ros_core (metapackage)
-- ~~  - ros_tutorials (metapackage)
-- ~~  - rosbag_migration_rule
-- ~~  - rosbash
-- ~~  - rosboost_cfg
-- ~~  - rosbuild
-- ~~  - rosclean
-- ~~  - roscpp_core (metapackage)
-- ~~  - roscpp_traits
-- ~~  - roscreate
-- ~~  - rosgraph
-- ~~  - roslang
-- ~~  - roslint
-- ~~  - rosmake
-- ~~  - rosmaster
-- ~~  - rosmsg
-- ~~  - rospack
-- ~~  - roslib
-- ~~  - rosparam
-- ~~  - rospy
-- ~~  - rosserial (metapackage)
-- ~~  - rosserial_client
-- ~~  - rosserial_msgs
-- ~~  - rosserial_python
-- ~~  - rosservice
-- ~~  - rostime
-- ~~  - roscpp_serialization
-- ~~  - python_qt_binding
-- ~~  - roslaunch
-- ~~  - rosunit
-- ~~  - rosconsole
-- ~~  - pluginlib
-- ~~  - qt_gui_cpp
-- ~~  - resource_retriever
-- ~~  - rosconsole_bridge
-- ~~  - roslz4
-- ~~  - rosbag_storage
-- ~~  - rostest
-- ~~  - rqt_action
-- ~~  - rqt_bag
-- ~~  - rqt_bag_plugins
-- ~~  - rqt_common_plugins (metapackage)
-- ~~  - rqt_console
-- ~~  - rqt_dep
-- ~~  - rqt_graph
-- ~~  - rqt_gui
-- ~~  - rqt_logger_level
-- ~~  - rqt_moveit
-- ~~  - rqt_msg
-- ~~  - rqt_nav_view
-- ~~  - rqt_plot
-- ~~  - rqt_pose_view
-- ~~  - rqt_publisher
-- ~~  - rqt_py_console
-- ~~  - rqt_reconfigure
-- ~~  - rqt_robot_dashboard
-- ~~  - rqt_robot_monitor
-- ~~  - rqt_robot_plugins (metapackage)
-- ~~  - rqt_robot_steering
-- ~~  - rqt_runtime_monitor
-- ~~  - rqt_service_caller
-- ~~  - rqt_shell
-- ~~  - rqt_srv
-- ~~  - rqt_tf_tree
-- ~~  - rqt_top
-- ~~  - rqt_topic
-- ~~  - rqt_web
-- ~~  - smach
-- ~~  - smclib
-- ~~  - std_msgs
-- ~~  - actionlib_msgs
-- ~~  - bond
-- ~~  - diagnostic_msgs
-- ~~  - geometry_msgs
-- ~~  - eigen_conversions
-- ~~  - kdl_conversions
-- ~~  - move_base_msgs
-- ~~  - nav_msgs
-- ~~  - rosgraph_msgs
-- ~~  - rqt_py_common
-- ~~  - sensor_msgs
-- ~~  - image_geometry
-- ~~  - map_msgs
-- ~~  - pcl_msgs
-- ~~  - shape_msgs
-- ~~  - smach_msgs
-- ~~  - std_srvs
-- ~~  - stereo_msgs
-- ~~  - tf2_msgs
-- ~~  - tf2
-- ~~  - trajectory_msgs
-- ~~  - control_msgs
-- ~~  - urdf_parser_plugin
-- ~~  - visualization_msgs
-- ~~  - geometric_shapes
-- ~~  - visualization_tutorials (metapackage)
-- ~~  - viz (metapackage)
-- ~~  - xmlrpcpp
-- ~~  - roscpp
-- ~~  - bondcpp
-- ~~  - bondpy
-- ~~  - collada_parser
-- ~~  - joint_state_publisher
-- ~~  - nodelet
-- ~~  - nodelet_tutorial_math
-- ~~  - pcl_conversions
-- ~~  - pluginlib_tutorials
-- ~~  - roscpp_tutorials
-- ~~  - rosout
-- ~~  - cv_bridge
-- ~~  - diagnostic_aggregator
-- ~~  - diagnostic_updater
-- ~~  - diagnostic_common_diagnostics
-- ~~  - dynamic_reconfigure
-- ~~  - filters
-- ~~  - message_filters
-- ~~  - image_transport
-- ~~  - rosnode
-- ~~  - rospy_tutorials
-- ~~  - rostopic
-- ~~  - roswtf
-- ~~  - rqt_gui_cpp
-- ~~  - rqt_gui_py
-- ~~  - rqt_image_view
-- ~~  - self_test
-- ~~  - smach_ros
-- ~~  - tf2_py
-- ~~  - topic_tools
-- ~~  - rosbag
-- ~~  - actionlib
-- ~~  - actionlib_tutorials
-- ~~  - diagnostic_analysis
-- ~~  - nodelet_topic_tools
-- ~~  - rqt_launch
-- ~~  - tf2_ros
-- ~~  - tf
-- ~~  - fake_localization
-- ~~  - gmapping
-- ~~  - interactive_markers
-- ~~  - interactive_marker_tutorials
-- ~~  - laser_geometry
-- ~~  - map_server
-- ~~  - amcl
-- ~~  - pcl_ros
-- ~~  - robot_pose_ekf
-- ~~  - tf2_kdl
-- ~~  - tf_conversions
-- ~~  - turtlesim
-- ~~  - turtle_actionlib
-- ~~  - turtle_tf
-- ~~  - turtle_tf2
-- ~~  - urdf
-- ~~  - collada_urdf
-- ~~  - kdl_parser
-- ~~  - robot_state_publisher
-- ~~  - rviz
-- ~~  - librviz_tutorial
-- ~~  - rqt_rviz
-- ~~  - rviz_plugin_tutorials
-- ~~  - rviz_python_tutorial
-- ~~  - urdf_tutorial
-- ~~  - visualization_marker_tutorials
-- ~~  - voxel_grid
-- ~~  - costmap_2d
-- ~~  - nav_core
-- ~~  - base_local_planner
-- ~~  - carrot_planner
-- ~~  - clear_costmap_recovery
-- ~~  - dwa_local_planner
-- ~~  - move_slow_and_clear
-- ~~  - navfn
-- ~~  - global_planner
-- ~~  - rotate_recovery
-- ~~  - move_base
-- ~~  - xacro
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
CMake Error at catkin/cmake/catkin_workspace.cmake:95 (message):
 This workspace contains non-catkin packages in it, and catkin cannot build a non-homogeneous workspace without isolation.  Try the 'catkin_make_isolated' command instead.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
CMakeLists.txt:63 (catkin_workspace)
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
Invoking "cmake" failed
pi@gps_pi:~/ros_catkin_ws $ roscd rviz
pi@gps_pi:/opt/ros/indigo/share/rviz $ su -
Password:
root@gps_pi:~# ls
comm1  minicom.log
root@gps_pi:~# logout
```

Above it is my errors.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/249164/cmake-error:workspace-contains-non-catkin-packages-in-it/) by [jimmyjiao](https://answers.ros.org/users/27100/jimmyjiao/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2016-12-01

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

self-answering: http://answers.ros.org/question/212996/catkin_make-invoking-cmake-error-in-raspberry-pi-2/
Here someone has the same problem, maybe I should create another individual workspace for package I want to use.

---

Originally posted by [jimmyjiao](https://answers.ros.org/users/27100/jimmyjiao/) with karma: 41 on 2016-12-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-12-01**:
Yes, that's the accepted approach: create a base workspace, use that to build ROS from source, install it. Then create a second workspace that *extends* the first (just `source /path/to/first/workspace/install/setup.bash`), and put other pkgs in that.

**Comment by [amadojoao](https://answers.ros.org/users/47187/amadojoao/) on 2019-10-16**:
I don't know how to do this, where can i find a tutorial?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-10-16**:
See [wiki/catkin/Tutorials/workspace_overlaying](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/workspace_overlaying).

**Comment by [Ashkr](https://answers.ros.org/users/45549/ashkr/) on 2020-06-09**:
@gvdhoorn; Hi, please help me to resolve this issue. I tried to add this package *https://namesdir.com/mirrors/wiki.ros.org/dynamixel_workbench_controllers(2f)Tutorials(2f)VelocityControl.html* to my current 'ros_catkin_ws' and compiled with this:
*$ sudo ./src/catkin/bin/catkin_make_isolated --install -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release --install-space /opt/ros/kinetic -j2*. Its successfully compiled but when I tested it with 'catkin_make', its failed with these errors. Please Help!

CMake Error at catkin/cmake/catkin_workspace.cmake:95 (message):
This workspace contains non-catkin packages in it, and catkin cannot build
a non-homogeneous workspace without isolation.  Try the
'catkin_make_isolated' command instead.
**Call Stack (most recent call first):**
CMakeLists.txt:67 (catkin_workspace)

-- Configuring incomplete errors occurred!
See also "/home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/pi/ros_catkin-ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".